# Can you get access to Facebook friends email addresses with api

Tags: php, facebook, api, permissions, facebook-php-sdk

Can you get the email adress of your friends? The [permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/user-friend-permissions/) say it is not. I try this:

```
getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email'))
```

This allows me to get the email of the user that logs in the application. I would like the email of his friends.

How is it possible to import Facebook to Yahoo for example.

Comment: If the documentation says it's not possible, I would believe it and leave it alone.

Comment: Believe it or not, Facebook respects people's privacy.  Stop trying to circumvent their rules and spam people.  It'll get your app priveleges revoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible and neither should it be.